# Crawl DHT of a private network from outside

Tags: kademlia, libp2p

I am running a private libp2p network with the help of docker containers where the members are using Kademlia DHT to store data. Is there a way to retrieve all the multi-addresses in that network from outside with just one known multi-address?

I tried implementing it with Kademlia, and identify but when I query the DHT I just get the bootstrapped node which I am starting with. I dont get the others.